# EditText doesnt take value

Tags: java, android, input, android-textinputedittext

I have two EditText's, title input and desc input.

```
    final EditText naslov_comm = view.findViewById(R.id.naslov_comm);
    final EditText opis_comm = view.findViewById(R.id.opis_comm);
    final String inputnaslov = naslov_comm.getText().toString();
    final String inputopis = opis_comm.getText().toString();
    objavicom_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.objavicom_btn);

    objavicom_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CommentDTO commentDTO_a = new CommentDTO(inputnaslov, inputopis);

            sendNetworkRequest(id_post, user_pref, commentDTO_a);

        }
    });
```

Everytime my button is clicked, it's supposed to take those inputs, but it returns empty string

```
inputnaslov=""
inputopis=""
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hrle.android_portal.ReadPostActivity"
android:background="?android:windowBackground"
android:id="@+id/arpfc">



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/naslov_comm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Unesite naslov"
    android:inputType="text"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/opis_comm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/naslov_comm"
    android:hint="Unesite opis"
    android:inputType="text" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/objavicom_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/opis_comm"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Objavi"
    />
```

Could final be causing this problem, or maybe android:inputType="text" in my xml?

Comment: Are you using fragment?

Comment: yes I do, I think that's the problem

Answer (score 2):

You should add **`getText().toString()`** into **`onClick(View view)`** Section just.

```
 objavicom_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.objavicom_btn);

    objavicom_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        final String inputnaslov = naslov_comm.getText().toString();
        final String inputopis = opis_comm.getText().toString();
        CommentDTO commentDTO_a = new CommentDTO(inputnaslov, inputopis);
        sendNetworkRequest(id_post, user_pref, commentDTO_a);


        }
    });
```

Comment: @MarkoLazarevic How? You should add Break Point and DEBUG please.

Answer (score 1):

The place where you are reading values of edittext is not correct. At that time your editText must have empty value (as that is declaration block where you are trying to read a dynamic value).

So when you want to read a value dynamically, best place is to read it on click of button.

---

Move value reading code in onclick on buttons

```
inputnaslov = naslov_comm.getText().toString();
inputopis = opis_comm.getText().toString();
```

---

Like below

```
objavicom_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           // Read latest value of edittexts 
            inputnaslov = naslov_comm.getText().toString();
            inputopis = opis_comm.getText().toString();

            CommentDTO commentDTO_a = new CommentDTO(inputnaslov, inputopis);

            sendNetworkRequest(id_post, user_pref, commentDTO_a);

        }
    });
```

Comment: @MarkoLazarevic What is not working now? Still empty text? If yes do you have anything into editetxt?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is, you get value from EditText when it was blank, then you are further using that blank string.
Correct way is to get text of EditText when user clicks on button.

```
final EditText naslov_comm = view.findViewById(R.id.naslov_comm);
final EditText opis_comm = view.findViewById(R.id.opis_comm);
findViewById(R.id.objavicom_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String inputnaslov = naslov_comm.getText().toString();
        final String inputopis = opis_comm.getText().toString();
        CommentDTO commentDTO_a = new CommentDTO(inputnaslov, inputopis);
        sendNetworkRequest(id_post, user_pref, commentDTO_a);
    }
});
```

**Update**

> Could final be causing this problem, or maybe android:inputType="text" in my xml?

No! It will not make problem, it is just [input type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType) like if you set it number, user will see numbers keyboard and can enter numbers only to editext.

Comment: This is the correct way for thing you wanted, if it still does not work, perhaps class changes did not refracted in your app. Try uninstalling and installing fresh app again.